# To find a pattern in python in a url

Tags: python, regex

I have a cache log file on which I have to eliminate the lines in which the url having ".js?" 
".gif?", ".png?" has to be eliminated.

```
logfile=open('/home/prasanna/Downloads/processed_file','r')
cleanfile=open('/home/prasanna/Downloads/cleaned_file','a')
with logfile:
    for line in logfile:
         line_words=line.split()
         url=line_words[6].split('.')
         #pattern if_condition
              cleanfile.write(line)
cleanfile.close()
logfile.close()
```

I need to write the lines from the processed_file to cleaned file whenever a line in processed_file doesnt have the above said pattern

for example:
1168414758.369 723 80.126.67.6 TCP_MISS/304 380 GET http://c.msn.com/c.gif?[07lKw.F:jbQg5CY03lJ8T.] - DIRECT/207.46.216.62 -

1168416013.376 621 233.7.37.201 TCP_MISS/304 162 GET http://mobile9.us.intellitxt.com/v3/func_033.js?[15zZlncWMGXv5PQNupu.tC] - DIRECT/205.147.84.25 -

Comment: What do you mean by eliminating lines? could you expand your example along with expected output?

Comment: What have you tried so far? This sounds more like "do this for me!" than it sounds like "how do I do this?"

Comment: Elimating in the sense I have rewrite 226789 lines file  into other file which I am able to do but I couldnt do that pattern finding one.

Comment: just split and use in, `".gif?" in s.split("GET")[1]` or `".gif?" in s` if it won't appear anywhere else

Comment: You can do this with basic string manipulation, a simple regex, a standard-logfile-format parsing library, a custom parser, or probably various other ways. Pick one, try it, and when you get stuck, ask a specific question to get you past where you're stuck.

Comment: grep will do that for you. `grep -v '(\.js\?|\.gif\?|\.png\?)' input_file > output_file`.  If you really need to do it in Python, do a match for the regex in the grep command for each line.

Comment: Thank u for all the comments. I am new to stackoverflow. I have edited the question, please go through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by eliminate you mean not to write the line to cleaned file, then a simple check should do it.

```
logfile=open('/home/prasanna/Downloads/processed_file','r')
cleanfile=open('/home/prasanna/Downloads/cleaned_file','a')
with logfile:
    for line in logfile:
         line_words=line.split()
         url=line_words[6].split('.')
         if "gif?" not in line and ".png?" not in line and ".js?" not in line:
              cleanfile.write(line)
cleanfile.close()
logfile.close()
```

Comment: I meant to write the lines to a new file where the lines having the pattern are absent.

Comment: You can mark it as correct answer if it works. That way the question gets closed.

Answer (score 0):

Is this so hard?

```
for line in file:
    if ".gif" in line or ".png" in line or ".js" in line:
        line = ""
    else:
        pass
```